# How to get the "human-readable" part from an values\arrays.xml-file

Tags: android

I just can't figure out how to accomplish the following;

I'd like to display the "human readable form" (`refresh_interval_entries`), for example in a `Log.d()`, corresponding to what has been selected in `refresh_interval_values`.

- I have two arrays defined in `values\arrays.xml`:

  ```
  <string-array name="refresh_interval_entries" translatable="false">
      <item>1 minute</item>
      <item>2 minutes</item>
      <item>3 minutes</item>
  </string-array>
  <string-array name="refresh_interval_values" translatable="false">
     <item>60</item>
     <item>120</item>
     <item>180</item>
  </string-array>
  ```
- I save the selected value from `refresh_interval_values` in a ListPreference.

First I was thinking of doing something like;

```
String[] mEntries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.refresh_interval_entries);
```

But I don't think that will work since I can't get the correct index for `mEntries[index]`, since i can't use the values in `refresh_interval_values`.

I am **not** trying to display this in an Activity that extends `PreferenceActivity`, just in a normal Activity.
Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about on start of your application, you make a `HashMap` out of the two `arrays`:

```
HashMap<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
String[] mEntries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.refresh_interval_entries);
String[] mValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.refresh_interval_values);

for (int i = 0; i < mEntries.length; i++) {
    dictionary.put(mValues[i], mEntries[i]);
}
```

and use it like:

```
String entry = dictionary.get("60");
```

Comment: Nice one, I'll go with this one, seems neat enough!

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
   {
        ... 
        String[] mEntries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.refresh_interval_entries);
        String[] mValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.refresh_interval_values);
        Log.d(TAG, "120=" + getEntryFromValue("120", mEntries, mValues));
    }

private String getEntryFromValue(String value, String[] mEntries, String[] mValues) {
    for (int i=0; i < mValues.length; i++) {
        if (value.equals(mValues[i])) {
            // check mEntries length
            return mEntries[i];
        }
    }
    return "NOT FOUND";
}
```

Comment: Upvote for the nice solution, although I'm gonna go with the HashMap by Christiaan :-)